# Relationship between voltage and current of a power transformer

Tags: transformer

I'm currently analyzing data from a power transformer and I stumble over the circumstance that voltage and current is almost not related to each other. Since I'm not an engineer I wonder why is this?

From my knowledge, the voltage must drop when current flows but I know it is possible to build voltage-stable circuits. This is probably also valid for transformers because I think nobody would like to have a different voltage when (hundreds) ones neighbours need power as well.
Is this (simple) explanation correct or is there another reason?

Comment: Can you share your data? How did you measure?

Comment: It is not true that voltage **must** drop when current flows, but that is usually the case for real circuits. Your first sentence is unclear. What do you mean by "voltage and current is almost not related". What kind of relationship did you expect, and what kind of relationship did you find?

Comment: It is true that a transformer is a voltage stable circuit.The voltage should not drop more than a few percent, for large transformers, less than one percent. You need to study electric circuits and devices from the beginning. Your question is like jumping into the middle. The need to explain foundation concepts makes the question too broad. I am voting to close the question.

Comment: @winny Unfortunately not, as it is business restricted. But here you are able to get data from the european power grid ( https://open-power-system-data.org/ ).

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Alright, thanks! Not related to each other is drawn by the observation of the correlation coefficient between voltage and current. Almost not related.

Comment: @CharlesCowie I'm not studying or using circuits/devices, I watch the transformer from an analytical distance. As it is voltage-stabilized, the correlation between voltage and current should therefore be 0. No need for circuits here ;)

Comment: A transformer is an electrical device that has the characteristic that the output voltage is determine by the input voltage and the turns ratio, but affected by the small internal impedance. The word "stabilized" implies some kind of regulation feature. That really does not apply to a transformer. The input voltage is "stabilized" or regulated ti the extent that the grid is regulated. A transformer changes the voltage while adding only a little impedance that would tend to make the voltage drop when the current increases.

Comment: _"No need for circuits here ;)"_ I beg to differ, alternatively you are on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can model a transformer like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxy4ZT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I read about this resistance (let's say R1 here) which changes over time and increases the current. When the current increases, shouldn't the voltage decrease to keep the power balanced?

Comment: This model uses a constant R1. What changes is the voltage across the primary, which depends on the core flux.  Again ---- the feedback depends upon the core being what sums the primary and the secondary ampere-turns.